# apach2 block non-name-based virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost

I am using apache in Ubuntu 12.04. I set up my apache server using name-based virtual host, but it seems block other port when I want to access other port directly using IP address.

I run

```
sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer 88
```

want to get a simple server, but my browser cannot access port 88, it says'The connection has timed out'. So I am assuming my apache is blocking port 88 because I directly use IP address to visit, not a domain name.

Is there anyway to solve this?

=====================update====================

Problem solved.
Because I am using Amazon aws, they have security check for port open. Just need to add a rule for inbound in my aws console.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the port is blocked by the firewall. Port 88 is nonstandard and should not be enabled by default.

On Ubuntu, if `ufw` is used, you can enable connections to port 88 with:

```
sudo ufw allow 88
```

Or see the full documentation: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/firewall.html

Comment: I tried that, but it still does not work. Cannot access the port.